# Not able to run service using docker stack in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, prometheus, docker-swarm-mode

Here is the docker-compose file that I once used to successfully run docker container using docker-compose.

Now trying to deploy using the docker stack. My manager and workers node are ready.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:

    prometheus:
        image: prom/prometheus
        volumes:
            - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
        command:
            - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
        ports:
            - '9090:9090'
        deploy:
           mode: replicated
           replicas: 1
           placement:
               constraints:
                   - node.role == manager
```

**Command used:**

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml monitoring
```

Trying to run it in the manager node. Why is the service not running . checking if the service is running or not using `docker service ls` shows 0/1 as you can see in the figure bellow.

[image: docker service ls checking]

When trying to check the logs with `docker service logs <servicename>` Nothing gets loaded.

Where exactly am I missing the things. My ultimate goal being running the full docker monitoring service like cadvisor and node-exporter and all other required. I tried with this **https://github.com/stefanprodan/swarmprom/blob/master/docker-compose.yml**

> I have figured out the problem is in the replicated mode, runs well in global mode although.

**What error is here with the replicated mode. I don't think I  have a syntax error here. How to make it run in replicated mode and in the manager node only**

Comment: What does `docker service ps monitoring_prometheus` output (especially the error column)?

Comment: "failed to allocate gateway(1...."

Comment: I have done this to remove unwanted networks `docker network prune`  Now the service is running but not in the manager node and also not showing 1/1 in `docker service ls`

Comment: At best, you update your question with all these information to minimize the amount of comments (others have to read too) and you can also delete your comments here afterwards. (like I will do with this comment)

Comment: Could you re-run the `docker service ps --no-trunc monitoring_prometheus` (mind the `--no-trunc`)?

Comment: "failed to allocate gateway (10.0.0.1): Address already in use"

Comment: with `docker network prune` that goes away but the service doesnot run in the manager node

Answer (score 1):

If everything works well with the "docker-compose up" but you find the issues with "docker stack deploy". This is how I fixed it.

I am using docker in a Windows machines and docker uses a VirtualBox VM. You will need to do port forward to see the containers in the host machine.

The problem is related to the bind mount with the volumes.

See the path in the two scenarios below when I do docker inspect :

1. Docker-compose up:

```
"Mounts": [
{
"Type": "bind",
"Source": "/c/Users/Bardav/Documents/Large-Scale-Software Testing/PromptDocker/PromptDocker/app_users",
"Destination": "/app",
"Mode": "rw",
"RW": true,
"Propagation": "rprivate"
}
```

2. Docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.ymal store:

```
"Mounts": [
{
"Type": "bind",
"Source": "C:\\Users\\Bardav\\Documents\\Large-Scale-Software Testing\\PromptDocker\\PromptDocker\\app_viewer",
"Target": "/app/"
}
],
```

SOLUTION:

Update the path in the `docker-compose.yml` and it will work. For instance;

RELATIVE PATH NOT WORKING

```
reg_users:
    image: prompt_user_app
    build: ./app_users/    
    volumes:
      - ./app_users/:/app/
```

ABSOLUTE PATH WORKS FINE

```
reg_users:
    image: prompt_user_app
    build: ./app_users/    
    volumes:
      - "/c/Users/Bardav/Documents/Large-Scale-Software Testing/PromptDocker/PromptDocker/app_users:/app/"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the placement constraint on Swarm Master / Manager. I had faced a similar problem while trying to schedule visualiser or portioner container on the master node using Azure Container Service. You can check the status of the master. If it is in Puased state you can make it active 
I had shared my experience at https://www.handsonarchitect.com/2017/11/visualize-docker-swarm-in-azure.html

Comment: It's not in the pause mode it is `active`

Comment: How many nodes do you have in the Swarm cluster? Ideally it should not matter since you are placing the constraint to schedule the container on Master. Can you check if port 9090 on the host is not used by any other service?